# How to set enable alternate keys with Microsoft.AspNet.OData version 6

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata

In **Microsoft.AspNet.OData** V5.9.1 and lower, you could enable alternate keys by calling EnableAlternateKeys() in the WebApiConfig.cs like so:

```
config.EnableAlternateKeys(true);
```

This option has been removed along with others like  :

```
config.EnableCaseInsensitive(true);
```

How do you turn the EnableAlternateKeys option on in **Microsoft.AspNet.OData** V6+?

Comment: The same happened with the EnableEnumPrefixFree method. For the last one, it seems an issue was raised in the OData github repo: [link](https://github.com/OData/WebApi/issues/904). You might comment there as well

Answer (score 3):

This has changed in OData WebAPI 6. Since v6 Dependency Injection has been introduced (see [docs](http://odata.github.io/WebApi/#13-04-DependencyInjection)). This means the old way of configuring your service has been changed. From now on you should register all necessary services and routes in the MapODataServiceRoute method

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    // Web API configuration and services
    config.Count().Filter().OrderBy().Expand().Select().MaxTop(null);

    setErrorDetailPolicy();
    var model = BuildEdmModel();

    // Web API routes
    config.MapODataServiceRoute("routeName", "routePrefix", builder =>
        builder.AddDefaultODataServices()
        .AddService<IEdmModel>(ServiceLifetime.Singleton, s => model)
        .AddService<IEnumerable<IODataRoutingConvention>>(ServiceLifetime.Singleton, sp => ODataRoutingConventions.CreateDefaultWithAttributeRouting("routeContact", config))
        .AddService<ODataUriResolver>(ServiceLifetime.Singleton, s => new AlternateKeysODataUriResolver(model))
    );
}
```

The important line here is the last one:

```
.AddService<ODataUriResolver>(ServiceLifetime.Singleton, s => new AlternateKeysODataUriResolver(model))
```

After this is enabled I found that my model had issues recognizing the `AddAlternateKeyAnnotation` extension method. This was solved by casting the instance to an `EdmModel` (instead of using the `IEdmModel` it was). My ModelBuilder class looks something like this:

```
    internal static IEdmModel GetModel()
    {
        ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
        builder.Namespace = "MyNamespace";

        var personsSet = builder.EntitySet<PersonDTO>("Persons");
        builder.EntityType<PersonDTO>().HasKey(k => k.Id);

        var model = builder.GetEdmModel();

        // model is built, add alternateKey annotation as necessary
        // first, find entity type
        IEdmEntityType t = model.FindDeclaredEntitySet("Persons").EntityType();

        // now find the properties we want to use as alternateKey
        var firstNameProp = t.FindProperty("FirstName");
        var lastNameProp = t.FindProperty("LastName");

        // and finally add the annotation
        ((EdmModel)model).AddAlternateKeyAnnotation(t, new Dictionary<string, IEdmProperty> {
            {
                "FirstName", firstNameProp
            },
            {
                "LastName", lastNameProp
            }
        });

        return model;
    }
```

Note that there are still a couple of convenience methods. From the documentation:

> You might also find that we still preserve the previous overloads of
>   MapODataServiceRoute which take batch handlers, path handlers, HTTP
>   message handlers, etc. They are basically wrapping the first overload
>   that takes a configureAction. The reason why we keep them is that we
>   want to give the users convenience to create OData services and
>   bearings to the APIs they are familiar with.

If you're wondering what the first line does:

```
config.Count().Filter().OrderBy().Expand().Select().MaxTop(null);
```

This is because in OData v6 by default all query options are disabled (again, see [docs](http://odata.github.io/WebApi/#13-01-modelbound-attribute)). You should either enable them on each controller/action, or do as I did, and enable them globally (which is what the above line does).

Comment: I don't see how what you've shown above re-enables the AddAlternateKeyAnnotation functionality for models.

Comment: Note that the modelbuilding part is different from the configuration of the OData service. Your question seemed to be only about the configuration part.
Anyway, adding the alternateKey annotation should work the same as it used to. See updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Something missing from jonathan.meesschaert answer is the signature for your action in the OData controller.

In my case I had the following alernate key:

```
((EdmModel)edmModel).AddAlternateKeyAnnotation(
entityType,
new Dictionary<string, IEdmProperty>() {
    { "Text", edmProperty }
});
```

and the asociated controller action was:

```
public MenuItem Get([FromODataUri]string keyText)
```

Note that you don't need to use `[HttpGet]` or `[ODataRoute("Menus(Text={Text})")]` to get it working. However, the crucial part is that **I had to append *key* to the parameter name**. Without that it didn't work on OData v7.1.0